# abrir un QMessageBox dentro de un QMainWindows ya abierto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

buscando en red para poder manipular ventanas, desde una ventana principal, llegue a poder realizarlo, lo que no encuentro aun, es ya ejecutando el programa, en el login al poner tanto user y password como admin, me debe salir un QMessageBox, con cualquier mensaje ("bienvenido"). Me corre todo cuando en vez de poner el QMessageBox, llamo a otra ventana PD: las otras llamadas de funciones me funcionan, las he probado sin el QMessageBox y corre normal, Tengo Python 3.7.1

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import *

class login(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(login, self).__init__()    
        loadUi('login.ui', self)
        rutaDeImagen = "C:/Users/AlvaroMartin/Desktop/rostro.jpg"
        self.loginTLfoto.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(rutaDeImagen))
        self.loginJBIngresar.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)


    def buttonClicked(self, e):
        if(self.loginTFusuario.text() == "admin" and self.loginTFcontra.text() == "admin"):

            rutaDeImagenA = "C:/Users/AlvaroMartin/Desktop/admin.jpg"
            self.loginTLfoto.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(rutaDeImagenA))

            #self.loginJBIngresar.clicked.connect(self.loginCheck)
            self.loginCheck()
            self.cambiosEnLogin()

            #self.showMessageBox('Warning','Invalid Username And Password')

            #self.abrirVentanaAdmin()

            # se agregara la opcion de que cambie la foto del admin 
        else:
            self.cambiosEnLogin()
            self.abrirVentanaUsuario()
            self.loginJBIngresar.clicked.connect(self.abrirVentanaUsuario)


    def loginCheck(self):
        print("UNA LINEA ANTES DEÑ MSSBOX ")
        self.showMessageBox('Warning','Invalid Username And Password')
        print("DESPUES DEL MSSBOX")

    def showMessageBox(self,title,message):
        msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle(title)
        msgBox.setText(message)
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgBox.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Si a alguien le sirve, ya pude hacerlo, no se si es porque sobrecargaba con la importacion de todos los modulos de (from PyQt5 import *), es lo que creo, pero tambien pudo ser por que movi otras cosas, les dejo el codigo con el cual si me funciona todo normal. Saludos

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class login(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(login, self).__init__()    
        loadUi('login.ui', self)
        rutaDeImagen = "C:/Users/AlvaroMartin/Desktop/rostro.jpg"
        self.loginTLfoto.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(rutaDeImagen))
        self.loginJBIngresar.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self, e):
        if((self.loginTFusuario.text() == "" and self.loginTFcontra.text() == "") or (self.loginTFusuario.text() == "" and self.loginTFcontra.text() != "") or (self.loginTFusuario.text() != "" and self.loginTFcontra.text() == "") ):
            QMessageBox.information(self, "ERROR", "Complete ambos campos, o Ingrese correctamente sus datos", QMessageBox.Ok)
            self.cambiosEnLogin()
        else:
            if(self.loginTFusuario.text() == "admin" and self.loginTFcontra.text() == "admin"):

                rutaDeImagenA = "C:/Users/AlvaroMartin/Desktop/admin.jpg"
                self.loginTLfoto.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(rutaDeImagenA))

                QMessageBox.information(self, "Correcto", "Bienvenido Administrador", QMessageBox.Ok)

                self.cambiosEnLogin()
                self.abrirVentanaAdmin()

            else:
                QMessageBox.information(self, "Correcto", "Bienvenido Usuario", QMessageBox.Ok)
                self.cambiosEnLogin()
                self.abrirVentanaUsuario()

    def cambiosEnLogin(self):
        self.loginTFusuario.setText("")
        self.loginTFcontra.setText("")
        rutaDeImagen = "C:/Users/AlvaroMartin/Desktop/rostro.jpg"
        self.loginTLfoto.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(rutaDeImagen))

    def crearMensaje(self):
        a = QMessageBox()
        a.information(self,"Advertencia","Llenelos")
        a.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Llevo varios días sin encontrar el error (y sigo sin encontrarlo); esta es mi rutinita para el mensaje:

```py
def Mensaje(self, mensaje):

    msgBox = QMessageBox()
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("titulo")
    msgBox.setText(mensaje)
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
    msgBox.exec_()
```

Solo cambié esas líneas por una línea vista en [esta respuesta](/a/208070):

```py
QMessageBox.information(self, "Titulo", "mensaje", QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Y ya no se cierra. Cabe señalar que tengo una ventana QMainWindow, que llama a otra QMainWindow y esta última llama a otra QDialog, y esta es la que se cierra al ejecutar el QMessageBox, en las otras trabaja normal.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera medalla. La zona de respuestas no es la adecuada para realizar preguntas. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, utiliza el enlace [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), haciendo referencia a esta si consideras que puede estar relacionada. Esta respuesta será eliminada.